# SQL concat few select into one big table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have table with data:

1. YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS - Number of views, number of clicks, etc..
2. YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS - ...

I want sum all those columns into sum value. 
Like:
1. YYYY/MM/DD - sum of views, sum of clicks

What I have done:
1. Query foreach column.
For views;

```
select 
  cast([EventTime] as date) as 'Date',
  Count([Id]) as 'Views'
from [TelemetryData] 
where [DiscountId] = '8773fd1b-f0c0-41fd-b0a0-ab8238f227f5'
  and [EventName]     = 'DiscountView'
group by cast([EventTime] as date)
order by cast([EventTime] as date) asc
```

Number of clicks per day:

```
select 
  cast([EventTime] as date) as 'Date',
  Count([Id]) as 'Clicks'
from [TelemetryData] 
where [DiscountId] = '8773fd1b-f0c0-41fd-b0a0-ab8238f227f5'
  and [EventName] =     'DiscountClick'
group by cast([EventTime] as date)
order by cast([EventTime] as date) asc
```

How I can sum all of them into one row per day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with checks and sums:

```
SELECT cast([EventTime] as date) as 'Date', SUM(case when [EventName]='DiscountClick' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Clicks', SUM(case when [EventName]='DiscountView' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Views'
from [TelemetryData] 
where [DiscountId] = '8773fd1b-f0c0-41fd-b0a0-ab8238f227f5'
and ([EventName] = 'DiscountView' or [EventName] = 'DiscountClick')
group by cast([EventTime] as date)
order by cast([EventTime] as date) asc
```

What has been changed:

We first were maded where column to filter both Views and Clicks.

Then we used SUM but with CASE when EVENT=SOMETHING we are adding 1, otherwise 0.

With your group, you will get both by days at one query.

Comment: Excellent! Thx! I have 7 more columns to sum so it's easy to add. Code:  SUM(case when [EventName]='DiscountView' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Views',
 SUM(case when [EventName]='DiscountClick' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Clicks',  I need CTR from Round(cast(Clicks) as float) / cast(Views as float) * 100, 2) as 'Average CTR'

Answer (score 0):

use SUM with CASE..

```
sum(case when [DiscountId] = '8773fd1b-f0c0-41fd-b0a0-ab8238f227f5'
  and [EventName] =     'DiscountClick' then noofclicks column else 0 end
) as clicks

sum(case when [DiscountId] = '8773fd1b-f0c0-41fd-b0a0-ab8238f227f5'
  and [EventName] =     'DiscountView' then view column else 0 end
) as views
```

and so on for other ....

```
from
table
group by cast([EventTime] as date)
order by cast([EventTime] as date)
```